# Migrate Windows XP to Xen HVM

Tags: windows, windows-xp, xen

I want to migrate a Windows XP machine to a Xen 4.1 HVM virtual machine with Windows XP installed (the custom software will only work with XP).

The software is custom made, and needs to be migrated across.

Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, backup everything.

Set up a test environment so that your new VM may run without interrupting operations of the physical host.

Jot down MAC adresses of the original hardware, you might need them for licensing.

Image the disk and copy it to your Xen dom0, keep a backup copy around or use LVM snapshots.

Create a Xen domU with the data extracted from the old host.

Boot up the VM and install GPL PV drivers:
http://wiki.univention.de/index.php?title=Installing-signed-GPLPV-drivers

Reactivate XP if needed.

Get some key users to test this new host and have them verify that everything is working correctly.

Shutdown the original host and move your VM from staging to production.

Comment: thanks, which software would you suggest for the image?

Comment: boot the host with your favourite linux livecd and use `dd`.